# "CORS Errors Persist Despite Using cors Middleware in Node.js and React App"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, error-handling, cors

I'm struggling with CORS problems in my Node.js (localhost:3000) and React (localhost:8000) app. I've added `cors` middleware to my server, but CORS errors persist when making requests from React. Here's a snippet:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

// ... other middleware

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000'));
```

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable CORS requests for a certain number of origins as shown below :

```
app.use(cors({ 
       origin: 'http://localhost:8000'
    }))
```